# Paperclip Error: uninitialized constant Paperclip (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Trying to install paperclip (the cloudfiles fork), but getting an error:

```
 config/enviroments/development.rb:28:in 'block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Paperclip (NameError)
```

This is how I installed everything.

gemfile:

```
gem 'cloudfiles', '>=1.4.9'
gem 'paperclip-cloudfiles', '~>2.3'
```

config/environment.rb

```
config.gem 'paperclip-cloudfiles', :lib => 'paperclip'
```

config/enviroments/development.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/ImageMagick/6.6.9-Q16/" #ImageMagick is at c:/ImageMagick/..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but if you're using Bundler, you don't need to call config.gem in your environment.rb. Maybe instead you should do:

```
gem 'paperclip-cloudfiles', '~>2.3', :require => 'paperclip'
```

Comment: You're a life saver my friend

Answer (score 0):

In your gemfile you could try:

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/minter/paperclip.git"
```

As Jack Chu stated you shouldn't need to list the gem in your environment.rb