# Rails server failed because of paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

The error message I got

```
/Users/Steve/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Paperclip (NameError)
from /Users/Steve/Desktop/myapp/config/environment.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
```

`environment.rb:40` is `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"`

and it is the path of ImageMagick. I wonder what the problem is and how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062970/paperclip-error-uninitialized-constant-paperclip-nameerror

Comment: I have tried both solutions and neither worked. I do not have cloudfiles gem installed.